как загрузит фулл карту в первом рендер
В своем проекте я использую библиотеку react-yandex-maps. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы карта была полностью загружена при первом входе пользователя в приложение. Если я проведу карту справа налево или сверху вниз, карта не должна повторно отображаться.

Вы хотите закэшировать вывод карты или отобразить её только при первом посещении?

да, надо закешировать

Загрузка регионов для работы offline реализована только в коммерческой версии мобильной библиотеки MapKit. JavaScript API, включая сторонние модули вроде react-yandex-maps загружать подложку для последующей работы без загрузки по сети не может.

Спасибо за ваш ответ! У меня платный apikey, теперь мне нужно закешировать карту в веб-проекте, как это сделать? Какой API мне следует использовать? В документации JavaScript API ничего конкретного не нашел
